# Is there any api service for showing portfolio performance of ethereum address

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, etherscan, dapp-development

I am working on dapp where i have to show portfolio performance of ethereum address. Can someone suggest me an api service which gives me all historic data of ethereum address show that i can plot a graph between portfolio value vs date.

Answer (score 0):

Zapper is real good for this:

https://docs.zapper.fi/zapper-api/api-getting-started

You can also use the PRO version of the Etherscan API, but this is not free.

Answer (score 0):

Zerion may be what you’re looking for: https://docs.zerion.io/websockets/getting-started/example

https://docs.zerion.io/websockets/namespaces/address

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

DeCommas Mission Control API might be a great solution for this, take a look at the documentation here - https://docs.decommas.io/

Mission Control is known for being very fast (under 250ms response time) and affordable, for most use-cases is completely free.